# Can I print to a log file or chat when an event occours?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to troubleshoot a shulker farm design.

This farm works flawlessly in vanilla, but on the server where I play, that uses paper, it breaks within minutes.

I am planning to set up a paper instance on my machine to try and "debug" the situation.

Is there a way to print to a log file or chat every time a (specific) shulker is damaged? (the print command would have to say what was the damage source as well)